# GIF animation changing background unexpectedly

Tags: animation, gif-format

I have the following animation that I wish to export as GIF

```
     ac = Table[Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], LightGray, Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1/\[Lambda], 0},{1/[Lambda],\[Lambda]}, {0, \[Lambda]}} /. \[Lambda] -> t]}], {t, 1, 4,0.1}];
    Export["gif.gif", ac, "GIF","DisplayDurations" -> 0.25]
```

but suddenly at the end a black background starts to appear, as shown below. What may be the flaw  ?

[image]

Comment: Why didn't you fix a `PlotRange` setting in your `Graphics[]`?

Comment: @J.M. I need it to stay the same height as it changes.

Comment: ...and that's exactly why you should have an explicit `PlotRange` setting!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- One workaround is using  `ListAnimate`

```
output = ListAnimate[ac];
Export["gif-1.gif", output, "DisplayDurations" -> 0.25, 
 "ControlAppearance" -> None]
```

- I also recommend to set `PlotRange`.

```
ac = Table[
   Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], LightGray, 
     Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1/λ, 
         0}, {1/λ, λ}, {0, λ}} /. λ ->
         t]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 4.5}}, Axes -> True], {t, 1, 
    4, 0.1}];
Export["gif-2.gif", ac, "GIF", "DisplayDurations" -> 0.25]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. `ListAnimate` is what I was looking for. Any idea about what may be causing the black background in my approach ?